# How to turn off Rspec's verbose logging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

When running our rspec suite of tests

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

The logs are cluttered with far to many log statements. In particular, the controller specs show things like this multiple times:

```
{"controller"=>"myController", "action"=>"create"}
```

I would like to get rid of these but can't find the source. There are no puts statements which match anything like this nor are there any Rails.logger calls. I'm assuming this is a log level issue but I could be wrong. Setting config.log_level in environment/test.rb has no effect.

The current rspec configuration looks like this

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.mock_with :rspec


  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.color_enabled = true
  config.tty = true
  config.formatter =  :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate
end
```

Any thoughts on how I might disable these type of logs?

Side note: Gemfile is using 'rails', '3.2.13' and  'rspec-rails', '2.14.0'

Comment: whats in that controller that would be outputting it? It's not something rspec is doing.

Comment: @sevenseacat I have no earthly idea. You sound certain about this but I honestly cannot find anything in the controllers which might be causing it. There are no logger, Rails.logger, puts or anything similar. Not sure where it could be coming from

Comment: well elaborate a bit more - is the message only coming up for a specific controller, or all controllers? a single action in each, or all actions? do the actions have something incommon?

Comment: Where are you seeing this - `log/test.log` perhaps? If so, then this is standard Rails logging and has nothing to do with rspec. You might find this useful: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Comment: When I've encountered this kind of situation, I've found it helpful to redefine `puts` with code that looks for the string being output and then dumps the call stack.  See https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/163538 for information on redefining `puts`

Comment: Found it. It was nothing to do with Rspec, Rails or anything platform specific. Someone had written 'p params' in a controller helper class which was spitting out the information to the logs. I may just delete this question since the original question and issue don't pair up at all.

Comment: @Rooktone please answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @fotanus Personally hate doing that. Will do it tomorrow.

Comment: @Rooktone If you don't do, this question will always show as unanswered, and brings people to read it dozen of times and lose time until see that the answer is in a comment. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 31):

In case someone comes across this same thread later on, I found that I had the same problem the author described, however, it came from having the Heroku `rails_12factor` gem in my Gemfile.

Another user said that the gem was causing double output for them: [Double console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966822/double-console-output)

As soon as I either commented it out or put it in the `:production` group, all of the verbose SQL output in my console went away.

So just another thing to check if you have the same problem, but the author's solution isn't what fixes it for you.

Comment: Putting rails_12factor in the production group (as in the README) did it!

Comment: You just saved me too.

Comment: Indeed, it was rails_12factor for me as well, putting it in the production group solved it :)

Comment: Thank god you solved it! Exact same problem I was having. Been driving me nuts for a while.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was not with Rspec after all. Instead Someone had written 'p params' in a controller helper. This question is not really valid due to this.

Relishapp's docs were very useful in uncovering this

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs