# Double console output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suddenly when I run my app locally, I get double console output. Does anybody know what might have caused this? The problem exists both when running Thin and Unicorn

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-05 22:21:21 +0200
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-05 22:21:21 +0200
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (299.5ms)
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (299.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (38.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (38.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 704ms (Views: 428.1ms | ActiveRecord: 52.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 704ms (Views: 428.1ms | ActiveRecord: 52.4ms)
```

This is my Gemfile

```
# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails'

gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'asset_sync'
gem 'authlogic', github: 'binarylogic/authlogic'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass', branch: '3'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'highcharts-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'pg'
gem 'prawn', '>= 1.0.0.rc2'
gem 'prawn_rails'
gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require: 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'rails_12factor' # required by Heroku
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'yui-compressor'

group :production do
  gem 'justonedb'
  gem 'unicorn-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'lol_dba' # To find table in need of indexes run 'lol_dba db:find_indexes'
  gem 'mailcatcher'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', require: false
  gem 'fuubar'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

My development.rb

```
# development.rb
Beerclub::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
end
```

and application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Beerclub
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'Copenhagen'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    config.i18n.default_locale = :da

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    # Needs to be false on Heroku
    config.serve_static_assets = false
    config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=31536000"

    # Add the fonts path
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'fonts')

    # Precompile additional assets
    config.assets.precompile += %w( *.svg *.eot *.woff *.ttf )
    config.assets.precompile += %w( *.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif )
  end
end
```

Comment: Take a look at your gems make sure that you don't have a duplicate in there

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza Bundler usually warns when you have a duplicate gem.

Answer (score 12):

in regards to rails_12factor - if you change the line in the Gemfile to:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

you will no longer see the double output in the console while debugging, etc.

Comment: Fixed my problem, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 11):

I've noticed this happens because of the `rails_12factor` gem. If you comment out `gem rails_12factor` from your `Gemfile` the double output should go away. My guess is that the double output isn't important to worry about since you need the gem anyways for Heroku.
As for why the `rails_12factor` gem causes this I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have code like this in your application:

```
<img src="#">
```

Rails sometimes makes duplicate records because of this also.

You may try doing:

```
rake assets:clean
```

Or maybe, commenting out this line in development.rb, might work:

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

As a last try, you may even try changing the folder of the application and then start the server to see the result.

Cheers!

Comment: Please take the time to use proper grammar in your answers. Don't use "u" when you mean "you". Proper nouns, like "rails" are capitalized. Thanks.

Comment: sure, 'll Keep ThaT In minD

Comment: I'm not sure commenting out "config.active_support.deprecation = :log" is a good idea, nor going to solve the problem.  The comment says "#Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger".

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it shows that duplicates are happening inline, ie.

```
A
A
B
B
C
C
```

If instead you are seeing what appears to be two back-to-back duplicate requests, ie:

```
A
B
C

A
B
C
```

You should strongly consider @aelor's answer of hunting down a `<img src="#">` or a similar self-referential url tag. I spent hours trying to figure out why my application was appearing to make two duplicate requests, and after reading @aelor's answer I found

```
%link{href: "", rel: "shortcut icon"}/
```

in my code! It was causing every page of my production app to be double rendering!!!! So bad for performance and so annoying!

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 4.2 and the time of this posting, the only solution I'm aware of is to remove rails_12factor from the Gemfile.

Adding `group: :production` no longer prevents the double-logging.  There is an open issue with heroku on github:

https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

We found this was caused by running the Rails server via

```
$ rails server
```

rather than

```
$ thin start
```

When using the latter, the double-logging problem goes away. Unfortunately we didn't have time to lock down the cause, we just changed the way we launched Thin and moved on.